# How to show an applovin appopen ad when cold start in android

Tags: java, android, mobile-development, applovin

How to show an applovin ad while the cold start in android.

I am trying to show an applovin appopen ad and set the appopenManager while oncreate of Splash Activity.

SplashActivity.java

```
appOpenManager = new AppOpen(this);
```

AppOpen.java

```
public class AppOpen implements LifecycleObserver, MaxAdListener{
    private MaxAppOpenAd appOpenAd;
    private final Context context;
    private boolean canShowAds;

    public AppOpen(MaxAppOpenAd appOpenAd, Context context) {
        this.appOpenAd = appOpenAd;
        this.context = context;
    }
    public AppOpen(final Context context) {
        ProcessLifecycleOwner.get().getLifecycle().addObserver(this);
        this.context = context;
        appOpenAd = new MaxAppOpenAd(ApplovinIntAndNative.getInstance(context).applovinAppOpenAdUnitId(), context);
        appOpenAd.setListener(this);
        appOpenAd.loadAd();
    }

    private void showAdIfReady() {
       
        if (RemovedAd.prouser) {
            if (appOpenAd == null || !AppLovinSdk.getInstance(context).isInitialized()) return;

            if (appOpenAd.isReady()) {
                appOpenAd.showAd(ApplovinIntAndNative.getInstance(context).applovinAppOpenAdUnitId());
            } else {
                appOpenAd.loadAd();
            }
        }

    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_START)
    public void onStart() {
        showAdIfReady();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoaded(MaxAd ad) {
        LogUtils.LOGD("onAdLoaded Applovin Appopen");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdDisplayed(MaxAd ad) {
        LogUtils.LOGD("onAdDisplayed Applovin Appopen");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdHidden(MaxAd ad) {
        appOpenAd.loadAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdClicked(MaxAd ad) {
        LogUtils.LOGD("onAdClicked Applovin Appopen");
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdLoadFailed(String adUnitId, MaxError error) {
        appOpenAd.loadAd();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAdDisplayFailed(MaxAd ad, MaxError error) {
        LogUtils.LOGD("onAdDisplayFailed Applovin Appopen");
        appOpenAd.loadAd();
    }
}
```